# Android update widget ListView

Tags: android, service, android-listview, refresh

I'm working on a app with a widget which I want to update on a regular basis. I've set android:updatePeriodMillis="3600000" but my ListView doesn't update. What is it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please check if your onUpdate(...) function getting call or not. If onUpdate() is getting called after update period, you need to call `notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged()` for ListView's adapter; in-order to update it.

```
AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context); 
int[] ids = mgr.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, AppWidgetProvider.class));
mgr.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(yourWidgetId, R.id.list_view);
```

Comment: Widget View factorys don't use adapters, atleast mine doesn't. How do you get this adapter object?

Comment: If your ListView is dirty(There is some change in List), then you can call invalidate() of ListView to force redraw.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're talking about regular ListViews which I do know how to handle. I'm asking about ListView in widgets where there are no ListView objects to work with.

Comment: Sorry to use app terminology. :(
You can call notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged inside AppWidgetProvider class.

Like

AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

int[] ids = mgr.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, AppWidgetProvider.class));

         mgr.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(id, R.id.list_view);


I will suggest you to see below topic(Keeping Collection Data Fresh): 

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html